# Auto-Fill using TextBox

Tags: google-apps-script, textbox, runtime-error

I had this working using a listbox, but now I want to change it to a textbox and I keep getting the error: "Error encountered: Cannot read property "1" from undefined."  I am not sure of the issue.  I had this same code working with a listbox and just tweaked it. I am needing help to solve the problem and wondering if I am down the wrong path.

**EDIT - ERROR OCCURANCE**

The error occurs when I put in a Student ID Number on the form, that references a Google Spreadsheet. When I hit Enter, I get the error and nothing auto-fills the other fields I have setup.

**Form Build (part)**

```
  //Create the form elements
  //Set DateBox to Today's Date
  var date = new Date()
  var txtDate = app.createTextBox().setName("txtDate").setId("txtDate").setValue(Utilities.formatDate(date, 'America/New_York', 'MM/dd/yyyy | hh:mm a')).setReadOnly(true).setEnabled(false).setStyleAttributes(lockedStyle);

  var lblStudentNumber = app.createLabel('Student ID#:');
  var hdlStudentInfo = app.createServerHandler('getStudentInfo').addCallbackElement(vrtMainPanel);
  var lbxStudentInfo = app.createTextBox().setId('lbxStudentInfo').setName('lbxStudentInfo').addChangeHandler(hdlStudentInfo).addChangeHandler(alertHideHandler);
//  var txtStudentNumber = app.createTextBox().setName("txtStudentNumber").setId("txtStudentNumber").setReadOnly(false).setEnabled(true).setStyleAttributes(normalStyle);

  var lblStudentName = app.createLabel('Student Name:');
  var txtStudentName = app.createTextBox().setName("txtStudentName").setId("txtStudentName").setText("Student Name").setReadOnly(true).setEnabled(false).setStyleAttributes(lockedStyle);
```

**getStudentInfo Function**

```
function getStudentInfo(e){
  var spSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1OhR5i8B89uK7XXW2Izdzim0LSngSr6KQPqL5ToeZTbo');
  var spStudentList = spSheet.getSheetByName('Schedule');
  var lstStudentID = spStudentList.getRange(2,1,spStudentList.getLastRow(),18).getValues();
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

//  var currTime = new Date();
//  var formattedTime = Utilities.formatDate(currTime,"hh:mm a");


  var txtStudentName = app.getElementById('txtStudentName');
  var txtTeacherName = app.getElementById('txtTeacherName');
//  var txtExt = app.getElementById('txtExt');
  var txtEmail = app.getElementById('txtEmail');
  var txtPeriod = app.getElementById('txtPeriod');
  var txtSubject = app.getElementById('txtSubject');

      txtStudentName.setText(lstStudentID[e.parameter.lbxStudentInfo][1] + " " + lstStudentID[e.parameter.lbxStudentInfo][2]);// sets Student's Name
      txtPeriod.setText("1st Period");// sets Period
      txtSubject.setText(lstStudentID[e.parameter.lbxStudentInfo][6]);// sets Subject
      txtTeacherName.setText(lstStudentID[e.parameter.lbxStudentInfo][7]);// sets Teacher's Name
      txtEmail.setText(lstStudentID[e.parameter.lbxStudentInfo][8]);// sets Email
//      txtExt.setText(lstStudentID[e.parameter.lbxStudentInfo][1]);// sets Ext
      return app;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us where the error occurs? And how did you run your script?

Comment: Yes, you are going down the wrong path - `UiApp` is deprecated. You should write this in `HtmlService`, where you can utilize modern browser-based JavaScript / etc.